# Windows XP taskbar application grouping

Tags: windows, taskbar

In normal windows XP sp2 you can group similar programs on the taskbar. Usually this grouping only occurs if the number of apps > x.

Does anyone know if x can be changed? I am trying to activate grouping if x > 1.

Comment: Grant: Try superuser.com

Answer (score 6):

Go download [TweakUI](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx) from microsoft. There is an option to set the number of windows to group. It is easier to set than modifying registry, moreoever you can set tweak other windows settings.

Comment: TweakUI is the way to go in XP. It gives you a lot of other tweaks you may find useful too. Plus, it is from MS, and light-weight.

Answer (score 2):

> Grouping occurs when the taskbar
>   becomes too crowded. This can be
>   changed by editing the registry. Type
>   regedit in the Run dialog box to open
>   the registry editor.
>
> Open
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced.
>
> If it is not already present, create a
>   new DWORD value called
>   TaskbarGroupSize
>
> Enter a value of 2 or greater. A value
>   of 2 will group similar buttons as
>   soon as the second window of an
>   application is created. A higher value
>   would allow numerous windows of the
>   same application before grouping
>   occurs.

By: http://thismatter.com/tutorials/software/windows-xp/managing-windows-with-taskbar.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try wsTaskborg Taskbar Organizer. Using it, you can create your own groups as and when you want, and assign a title to each group.

http://download.cnet.com/wsTaskborg/3000-2072_4-10632012.html

http://w-shadow.com/wstaskborg/